# IE9 appending svg to DOM when you have custom namespaces in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have this problem that I am stuck for several days now. I am trying to append a svg to the DOM. I have custom namespaces in it and when they are added into the DOM and you try to get the innerHTML property of the parent element to which you appended them you get them with some random namespaces. This happens only in IE9.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ns:attr="val" />';
 alert($("div").append(svg).html());
});
```

The output will be:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:NS1="" NS1:a:b="val" />
```

Any idea how could this be solved? I've tried to define the namespaces but it's not working again. Here's a jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/RwNqk/3/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get `NS1:a:b="val"`, I get `NS1:ns:attr="val"`. You can't have custom namespaces in HTML (text/html serialization) so whatever you are doing, it's wrong anyway.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have an HTML document—instead of XHTML—in your JSFiddle. HTML does not have custom namespaces, only XML/XHTML has that.

Secondly, you are using a `ns` namespace prefix without ever defining what that namespace is. It's a wonder that other browsers work at all.

Thirdly, even if you fix these problems, you (unfortunately) [can't use jQuery to jam elements into the DOM using previously-defined namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972852/add-xhtml-element-referencing-existing-namespace):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="hello"><head>
  <title>Using jQuery to add namespaced attribute</title>
</head><body>
  <div><p foo:bar="yes">one</p></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var xhtml = '<p foo:bar="no">two</p>';
    alert($('div').html());
    try{ $('div').append(xhtml); }
    catch(e){ alert(e);          }
  ]]></script>
</body></html>
```

The first alert shows that the custom namespace works:
`<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" foo:bar="yes" xmlns:foo="hello">one</p>`

The second alert shows the failure:

```
[Firefox] "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12"
[Chrome]  Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
[IE9]     DOM EXception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)
```

This has nothing to do with IE9 or SVG. It mostly has to do with jQuery. (You can set the `.innerHTML` of the DOM element in IE9 and FF and it will work as desired, but not with Chrome.)