# Add XHTML element referencing existing namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xhtml

#### The Question

Given an XHTML document with a custom namespace defined,

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="hello">…</html>
```

how can I use jQuery (or vanilla JavaScript) to add an element with an attribute referencing that namespace, specified as a string:

```js
var newElement = '<p foo:bar="please">add me</p>';
```

#### What Have You Tried?

```js
var xhtml = '<p foo:bar="no">two</p>';

try     { $('div').append(xhtml); }
catch(e){ alert(e);               }
// [FFv14]     "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12"
// [Chromev21] Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
// [IE9]       DOM EXception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)

try     { $('div')[0].innerHTML += xhtml; }
catch(e){ alert(e);                       }
// [FFv14]     Works!
// [IE9]       Works!
// [Chromev21] Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
```

#### Test Page ([Hosted](http://phrogz.net/tmp/js_add_element_referencing_namespace.xhtml))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="hello"><head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
  <title>Using JS to add element referencing custom namespace</title>
</head><body>
  <div><p foo:bar="yes">one</p></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var xhtml = '<p foo:bar="no">two</p>';

    try     { $('div').append(xhtml); }
    catch(e){ alert(e);               }

    try     { $('div')[0].innerHTML += xhtml; }
    catch(e){ alert(e);                       }
  ]]></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Perhaps the "right" answer is that an HTML-like XML document with custom namespaces is [not a valid XHTML 1.0 document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/normative.html#well-formed), and so the appropriate UA behavior is somewhat ill-defined.

Comment: It's more that the algorithm for innerHTML is somewhat unclear in an XML document. I would tend to use DOM methods such as createElementNS and setAttributeNS if I was adding to an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can come up with is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="hello"><head>
  <title>Using JS to add element referencing custom namespace</title>
</head><body >
  <div><p foo:bar="yes">one</p></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var xhtml = '<p foo:bar="no">two</p>';
    try { 
      var wrap = '<div xmlns:foo="' + $('div')[0].lookupNamespaceURI('foo') + '">'+ xhtml + '</div>';
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.innerHTML = wrap;
      $('div')[0].appendChild(el.firstChild.firstChild);
    }
    catch(e){ alert(e); }
  ]]></script>
</body></html>
```

Needs a bit of packaging up, but seems to work in  IE9, Chrome 21, FF 14, and Opera 12.